# Distorted wood texture

Tags: texturing

[image]

The left hand wood cladding panel in the image above is perfect but the right one looks fragmented and distorted. This happens continuously no matter what I tried (scaling, transforming). Any ideas what Im doing wrong? The texture used is the recommended one (blenderguru) from Poliigon.

Comment: Hello, there's no attached image, nor screenshots, could you please provide some, maybe even share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sounds like an unwrapping issue, please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try to recalculate normals = shift +n for me, some have ctrl+n, in edit mode. I had edges that became stripes instead of texture and did this.